# roxygenise just one .R file to add the file and its documentation to a package

Tags: r, roxygen2

I created a package and pushed it up to github, such that the `devtools` function `install_github()` function works for easy installation. i.e. the github repo file structure is such that the `DESCRIPTION` and `NAMESPACE` are at the top along with `/R` and `/man` folders that contain the `*.R` files and `*.Rd` files respectively for each function.

I now want to make some upgrades to it by adding in new functions.

I have all the relevant roxygen type (`#'`) text above the function in each new `.R` file, but can't find the `roxygen2` or otherwise relevant package function that will help read the `.R` file and write the relevant `.Rd` file hopefully this isn't too difficult... I think what I am asking for is, is possible to roxygenise just one file to add onto another existing package? so that it updates the DESCRIPTION, NAMESPACE files as well. so that i can just add, commit and push all these changes up to the remote repo on github?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you looking for the `document` function from `devtools`? This will create .Rd files from source in mylibrary/R.

It also updates `DESCRIPTION` and `NAMESPACE`.